# Loading same api data into div and modal dialog

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, bootstrap-modal, each

I'm trying to load data from a news API into both a div and a linked modal so that when the user clicks on the div, more information about that specific news article will be shown. I currently have the data loading into the divs but when clicked the same modal opens up for every article rather than the specific article clicked.

I have already tried loading two separate requests for both modal and div.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$.each(data, function(key,value){                 

      var output = '<div class="row">';

      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        output +='<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">'; 
        output += '<a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal1">'+'<div class="portfolio-hover">'+'<div class="portfolio-hover-content">'+'<i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x">'+'</i>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'<img class="img-fluid img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="'+ data.articles[i].urlToImage +'" alt="">'+'</img>'+'</a>'+'<div class="portfolio-caption">'+'<h4>'+ data.articles[i].title +'</h4>'+'<p class="text-muted">'+ data.articles[i].description +'</p>'+'<p>'+'<a href="'+ data.articles[i].url+'" target="_blank">Full story</a>'+'</p>'+'</div>';  
        output += '</div>';

     }
        output += '</div>'; // End row

      $('#headlines').html(output);
    }); 

    $.each(data, function(key,value){                 

      var output = '<div class="row">';

      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        output += '<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">';
        output += '<div class="modal-dialog">'+'<div class="modal-content">';
        output += '<div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">';
        output += '<div class="lr">'+'<div class="rl">'+'</div>'+'</div>';
        output += '</div>';
        output += '<div class="container">';
        output += '<div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">';
        output += '<div class="modal-body">';
        output += '<h2 class="text-uppercase">' + data.articles[i].title + '</h2>'+'<p class="item-intro text-muted">'+'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.'+'</p>'+'<img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="img/portfolio/01-full.jpg" alt="">'+'<p>'+'description'+'</p>'+'<ul class="list-inline">'+'<li>'+'Date: January 2017'+'</li>'+'<li>'+'Client: Threads'+'</li>'+'<li>'+'Category: Illustration'+'</li>'+'</ul>'+'<button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">'+'<i class="fas fa-times">'+'</i>'+'Close Project'+'</button>';
        output += '</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>';

     }
        output += '</div>'; // End row

      $('#headline').html(output);
    });
```

HTML

```
        <div class="row">
          <div id="headline">

          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id is 'headline' on the page and 'headlines' in the return from the first function. However, if you make them the same, the second will override the first (meaning what you've returned from the first function will be over-written).